# IIS + PHP + PS - New-ADUser Access Denied

Tags: php, powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

**Setup**:

- IIS 8.5
- PHP 7.1.7 x64
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- ActiveDirectory role deployed
- Powershell

I am building a website that will let Admins (but not domain admins, no Windows authentication enabled for that website) to create new AD users. Users will trigger a PS script via the website.

I have everything in place but I'm not able to trigger the PS script via PHP with proper rights.
Here is how the PS script is executed:

```
shell_exec('powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%s" %s', $File, $Params)
```

I am still getting

> New-ADUser : Access is denied

I configured Identity for that Application Pool with domain admin account but this did not help.

How can I accomplish this? 
Please advise.